# React-plotly: plot lines are invisible with WebGL (scattergl)

Tags: reactjs, plotly

I am using react-plotly for implementing a line graph inside a React component as in the below code. But, the plot is not visible. The reason for using scattergl is that I have a big set of data points to display in the production. Can anyone please help me with this issue. I am using react.js version 16.8.6 and react-plotly version 2.4.0.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { Row } from "reactstrap";
    import Plotly from "plotly.js"
    import createPlotlyComponent from 'react-plotly.js/factory';
    const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly);

    class Graph extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Plot
            data={[
              {
                x: [new Date(2019,12,19), new Date(2020,1,4)],
                y: [1,4],
                type: "scattergl",
                mode: "lines+markers",
                marker: {
                  line: {
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#404040'}
                  },
              },
            ]}
          />
        );
      }
    }

    export default Graph;
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>removing 'gl' from type `scattergl` should do the job</strike>

I just did a little research and found that using the pre-compiled component renders the line.

https://codesandbox.io/s/plotly-wh7l4?file=/src/Graph.js

I hope this helps.

Comment: Removing gl and using scatter does not apply webGL. I need to use webGL since I need to have a good performance for a large data set.

Comment: aw sorry, I didn't read carefully enough :X Just updated the answer. Hope this helps a bit more. Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. When I use import Plot from "react-plotly.js", I get a Javascript out of memory error. That is why I am using  import Plotly from "plotly.js"
    import createPlotlyComponent from 'react-plotly.js/factory';
    const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly); Can you please help we that issue.

Comment: does that only happen on making a production build or even just using the dev-server? have you tried increasing the heap size? I see quite a few problems from other ppl having the same issue building the project. https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3604